# Web application in Wordpress URI

Tags: wordpress, web-applications

Is it possible a especific URI in Wordpress call an web application (Example: https://mywebsite/my-application) and the rest of the site keep working as a ordinary wordpress?

If it is possible, how can i do it?

I have found no clue in anothers forums so far.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the folder `my-application` at the root of the WP install, and put your application inside this forlder.